# How to normalize impression bias when calculate the ctr?

Tags: statistics, click, ads, impressions

when we calculate the ctr from the data, like this

```
             #(click)
ctr   =  ----------------
          #(impressions)
```

if the number of impressions is too small, the calculted ctr is higher then the bigger impressions.
Is there any way to calculate normalized-ctr for evaluating each ads's performance?
How can I normalize?

Answer (score 0):

As you know, it is impossible the number of clicks would be higher than impressions! Because in theory, each click is accompanied by an impression all the time! Hence, `ctr <= 1` unless you have a technical problem in counting impressions or clicks.